# Ubuntu 18.04 - Google-chrome and Brave 1.0 constantly freezing and crashing

Tags: google-chrome, browser, brave

My google chrome has been crashing constantly for about a week. I don't have this problem in windows and it's effecting both my laptop and desktop where I use Ubuntu 18.04. I have no idea what could be causing this, but the browser is clearly unstable now. Even typing this I see that the browser is freezing up and I had several crashes before being able to finish this post. I have crash reports sitting in /var/crash, but I'm not sure how to filter out any good info. My FireFox is working perfectly, but Brave 1.0 is having the same stability issues. Does anyone know what's going on or know more about this problem? I'm in the dark on this one, any help would be great. Thank you.

Also, I tried removing Google-chrome and Brave 1.0 from the Ubuntu Software store and I reinstalled Google-chrome, but the problem is still the same. Should I do a purge of it than try to reinstall? What's the best way to uninstall it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Google Chrome. Try purging:

```
sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
```

After which, run:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This might help. But in case not, I recommend using Chromium:

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser
```

Chromium is basically the same as Chrome. When I faced this issue, I installed chromium and no problem afterward.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the crashing so far... i haven't had time to test it out with multiple tabs yet, but do you have any idea what's causing this problem and how to prevent it in the future? I don't even know what triggered the instability. Also, I used Chromium before, but it didn't perform as well as Chrome so I stopped using it - thanks for the advise anyway.

Comment: @Pachuca not sure. I got that problem when I updated chrome. BTW, chromium is not bad at all. You should try it

Comment: Had a chance to test things out more. I'm still getting crashes all the time. Not sure what to do at this point.